# How to handle Unicode character issues through python snowflake connector, while reading data from snowflake

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While reading data from snowflake using python snowflake connector, I am getting the following error:

> "InterfaceError: 252005: Failed to convert current row, cause: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 316: invalid continuation byte"

The string contains non-UTF-8 characters and the snowflake cursor is unable to return the value.
How to handle this situation, content is required.

Python version 3.7.6
Snowflake Python connector 5.5.1

Sample Code:

```py
import snowflake.connector 

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(user='user', password='pwd',account='act',warehouse='wrh', database='db', schema='schema', role = 'role' ) 
cur = ctx.cursor() 
cur.arraysize = 10000 
sql = """select longText from db.schema.table where textId = 1279""" 
cur.execute(sql) 
for element in cur: 
   print(element[0])
```

Sample Data:

```
xxxx: xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx Tx: xttxxh@xxxxx.xxx xx: xuxxxxt: xx: xxx00x0x3 : xxxxxxx0x= // Hxvx x xxxx xx-Xxxxx-xxx thxt xxxt xxxx. xxgx xhxx thxt thx xhxxxx (Uxxxxxxxxxxx) -----xxxgxxxx xxxxxgx----- xxxx: xxxx, xxux x xxV (Ux) [xxxxtx:xxux.x.xxxx.xxv@xxxx.xxx] xxxt: xxxxxxxxy, xxvxxxxx xx, x01x 1x:1x xx Tx: xxxxxáx xx xxxáxxx xx: xxxx, xxux x xxV (Ux) xuxxxxt: xx: xxx00x0x3 : xxxxxxx0x= // Hxvx x xxxx xx-Xxxxx-xxx thxt xxxt xxxx. xxgx xhxx thxt thx xhxxxx (Uxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

Comment: do you have an example of your code and the data?

Comment: Sample Code:
import snowflake.connector
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(user='user', password='pwd',account='act',warehouse='wrh', database='db',  schema='schema', role = 'role' )
cur = ctx.cursor()
cur.arraysize = 10000
sql = """select longText from db.schema.table where textId = 1279"""
cur.execute(sql)
for element in cur:
    print(element[0])

Comment: Sample Data: xxxx: xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx
Tx: xttxxh@xxxxx.xxx
xx: 
xuxxxxt: xx: xxx00x0x3 : xxxxxxx0x= // Hxvx x xxxx xx-Xxxxx-xxx thxt xxxt xxxx. xxgx xhxx thxt thx xhxxxx (Uxxxxxxxxxxx)


-----xxxgxxxx xxxxxgx-----
xxxx: xxxx, xxux x xxV (Ux) [xxxxtx:xxux.x.xxxx.xxv@xxxx.xxx] 
xxxt: xxxxxxxxy, xxvxxxxx xx, x01x 1x:1x xx
Tx: xxxxxáx xx xxxáxxx
xx: xxxx, xxux x xxV (Ux)
xuxxxxt: xx: xxx00x0x3 : xxxxxxx0x= // Hxvx x xxxx xx-Xxxxx-xxx thxt xxxt
xxxx. xxgx xhxx thxt thx xhxxxx (Uxxxxxxxxxxx)

Comment: I'm facing this issue as well. IMO, this should be fixed at the data level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `select longText`, try `select hex_encode(longText)`. This will transform whatever strange binary text lives inside that field into a safe to transport string. Then you can decode that back within the safety of Python.

For example, in sql:

```sql
select hex_encode('hello')
```

That returns `68656C6C6F`, which you can decode back in Python:

```py
>>> bytes.fromhex('68656C6C6F')
b'hello'
```

This technique will also give you some insights on what the weird character tripping up your code might be - and what encoding to use.

[image]

```py
>>> bytes.fromhex('68656C6C6F')
b'hello'
>>> bytes.fromhex('F09F9988')
b'\xf0\x9f\x99\x88'
>>> bytes.fromhex('F09F9988').decode('utf-8')
''
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe , i will try this and update here.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please upvote and accept stack overflow answers that are useful to you :)